# How to run a command separated in several variables in Bash?

Tags: command-line, bash

I would like to run a command made of several "pieces".

```
php="php"
options="-l"

for f in `git diff-index --cached --name-only HEAD | grep -e '\(php\|phtml\)$'`; do
   if [ -f $f ]; then
       # Here I want to run my command defined
       # in $php and $options and put the result in
       # $php_lint var
       # like this command would do:
       # php_lint=$(php -l $f)
       # but with something like that:
       # php_lint=eval $php $options $f
   fi
done
```

How can I do this?

**Update:**

After struggle on a particular point, I asked this question :

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760897/bash-error-command-not-found-running-a-command-stored-in-var/

Please have a look, it could also help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the options in an array, and expand it as `"${options[@]}"`

Ex.

```
$ cmd=ls
$ options=(-a -l -d)
$ f="foo"
```

then

```
$ result=$("$cmd" "${options[@]}" "$f")
```

giving

```
$ echo "$result"
drwxrwxr-x 2 user user 4096 Apr 20 08:07 foo
```

Comment: Thank you!

Could you edit your answer to add quotes on $cmd too? (it could be a command with spaces in it).

Comment: @darckcrystale you may find that if `$cmd` contains spaces, that also needs to be passed as an array (otherwise it will appear as a single string - I can't think of any actual *commands* that contain spaces - only commands + arguments).

Comment: You're right, it could be command with options. Do I need to do like with the $options var? Or should I set command in $cmd, and all options in $options var?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it is actually possible: `fname=new$'\n'line.sh; printf '#!/bin/sh\necho "Hello world"\n' > "$fname"; chmod 755 "$fname"; ./"$fname"`.  Anyone who does this, of course, deserves what they get.

Comment: @steeldriver The problem is for example the command could be something like `docker exec <container name> <command> <options>`, in this case, the $cmd could be `docker` and options `exec`, `<container name>`, `<command>`, `<options>`. That's sound a bit weird to me :/